# Uploading Wagtail images from outside of wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

In a Django model that cannot subclass `Page`, I want to convert an existing ImageField to use Wagtail images. I have redefined the field as:

```
avatar = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
)
```

The user needs to be able to upload an image to their profile view. In forms.py for the Django view, I have:

```
avatar = forms.ImageField(
    label='Your Photo', required=False,
    error_messages={'invalid': "Image files only"}, widget=forms.FileInput())
```

When I upload an image to the view, it crashes on:

```
Cannot assign "<InMemoryUploadedFile: filename.jpg (image/jpeg)>":
"UserProfile.avatar" must be a "Image" instance.
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is the field definition in the form, but I can't figure out what the right definition should be.

I know that I'll need to manually attach the image to the UserProfile and the Collection, but need to get past this error first. Or is it a bad idea to try and use individual WT fields in a non-WT model? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that the `avatar` ForeignKey field on your model is expecting to receive an instance of the `wagtailimages.Image` model. The `ImageField` on the form isn't capable of providing this - it only provides a file object. To make this work, you'll need to set up your form (which I'm assuming is a ModelForm) to create the `wagtailimages.Image` object at the same time as your own model. It should be possible to do this with a custom `save` method as follows:

- Rename `avatar = forms.ImageField` to something that doesn't clash with the `avatar` model field, such as `avatar_image`
- Ensure that `avatar_image` is included in your ModelForm's `fields` definition, but `avatar` isn't. At this point, `avatar_image` is just an extra field on the form, with no connection to the model.
- Define the following `save` method on the ModelForm:

  ```
  from wagtail.images.models import Image

  def save(self, commit=False):
      if not commit:
          raise Exception("This form doesn't support save(commit=False)")

      # build the instance for this form, but don't save it to the db yet
      instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)

      # create the Image object
      avatar = Image.objects.create(
          file=self.cleaned_data['avatar_image'],
          title="Image title"
          # you may need to add more fields such as collection to make it a valid image...
      )

      # attach the image to your final model, and save
      instance.avatar = avatar
      instance.save()
      return instance
  ```

Comment: Ah, makes sense, and this is a graceful approach. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I needed to change the import to `from wagtail.images.models import Image` for this to work. Thanks @gasman!

Comment: Hey gasman, could you please update the import statement in your example?