# Update Wagtail ModelAdmin wagtailimage.Image field from outside Admin View

Tags: wagtail

I have a Wagtail ModelAdmin which has a model with a field that is of type `wagtailimage.Image` with the below code:

```
partner_logo = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)
```

I have registered this ModelAdmin so I can edit it within the Wagtail Admin view and successfully upload an image to the `partner_logo` field. I can then update the image from the admin view.

I would like users to be able to update the image from the frontend. I have created a form that takes an image and passes it to the backend. I then try and update the image using the below code:

```
def upload_pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        partner_name = request.user.partner().partner_name
        partner_model = Partner.objects.get(partner_name=partner_name)

        partner_model.partner_logo.file = request.FILES['image']
        partner_model.partner_logo.save(update_fields=['file'])

        return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed('allowed only via POST')
```

This gets the correct model we want to update, sets the file for the `partner_logo` field and then saves the model. I believe I'm part of the way there as the image is uploaded to my media directory on save, however I guess I'm missing updating something else because it doesn't actually update the model.

Any advice would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551931/909446

Working code below:

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image


def upload_pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        partner_name = request.user.partner().partner_name
        partner_model = Partner.objects.get(partner_name=partner_name)

        new_logo = Image.objects.create(
            file=request.FILES['image'],
            title=f'{partner_name}-logo'
        )

        partner_model.partner_logo = new_logo
        partner_model.save()

        return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed('allowed only via POST')
```