# How to upload file in wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm new to wagtail I'm using AbstractEmailForm to build a form but I find out that forms in wagtail don't have field to upload file
I looked in wagtail documents to upload file but I didn't I found an example on internet but that for images I'm not looking for only images

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but can't comment yet.

The first question I have for you is, if you need the documents saved as Wagtail Documents. If not, you can simply follow the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/).

If you need to save them to Wagtail Docs, though, you need to do something similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551931/15513135) in your form's save, but instead of `Wagtail Images` save it as `Wagtail Document`

In either case, I recommend Django `Form` or `ModelForm`

Comment: need to create a form for customers that input name and email and upload 2 files pdf or docs is outside the admin in simple page

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @im-learning, have you worked on Django forms before? If not, is this form data (including the files) related to one of your Models?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Wagtail Streamforms](https://wagtailstreamforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It has file controls also which you can use on your site pages (outside admin).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).