# How to save image to model in wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

When I try to do this I get the following error "'BoundField' object has no attribute 'width'".

My model

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='+')

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.author)
```

Save method, error on Image.objects.create

```
class FeedbackPage(Page):
    ...
    def serve(self, request):
        post_data = request.POST or None
        review_form_class = ReviewForm
        if "review" in request.POST:
            review_form = review_form_class(post_data, prefix='review')
            new_review = Reviews()
            new_review.author = review_form['author']
            new_review.is_pub = False
            new_review.text = review_form['text']
            new_image = Image.objects.create(
            file=review_form['file'],
            title="Image title"
            )
            new_review.image = new_image
            if new_review.is_valid():
                new_review.save()
```

My form

```
class ReviewForm(TemplateForm):
    file = forms.ImageField()
```

I used part of code of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551931/9842214

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image

def save(self, commit=False):
    if not commit:
        raise Exception("This form doesn't support save(commit=False)")

    # build the instance for this form, but don't save it to the db yet
    instance = super(MyForm, self).save(commit=False)

    # create the Image object
    avatar = Image.objects.create(
        file=self.cleaned_data['avatar_image'],
        title="Image title"
        # you may need to add more fields such as collection to make it a valid image...
    )

    # attach the image to your final model, and save
    instance.avatar = avatar
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: You've left out the crucial part of the `serve` method - the file is coming from `review_form['file']`, but you haven't shown where the `review_form` variable is being initialised.

Comment: Wanted to remove as much redundant code as possible, here is a more complete class. Added code above

Comment: I have also tried overriding the save method for the form as in your answer. and still getting the width error. My local vars show 
kwargs 
{'file': None, 'title': 'Image title'}

Comment: some extra info:
review_form['file'] is empty, but request.POST['file'] have my image, so file=self.cleaned_data['file_img'] also empty, and i have no idea why

Comment: i did it, file=request.FILES['file']

Answer (score 0):

def chef_register(request):

```
if request.method == "POST" and "image" in request.FILES:

    fullname= request.POST.get('fullname')
    contact = request.POST.get('contact')
    license_no = request.POST.get('license_no')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    city = request.POST.get('city')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    address = request.POST.get('address')
    image= request.FILES['image']
    restaurent_name = request.POST.get('restaurent_name')

    ChefDetailsModel.objects.create(fullname=fullname,contact=contact,license_no=license_no,email=email,city=city,password=password,address=address,logo=image,restaurent_name=restaurent_name)



  <section class="py-5 overflow-hidden bg-primary" id="">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row flex-center">          
        <div class="row">      
           <div class="row" >
              <center><h1 style="color:white">Register Now</h1></center><br><br><br>
              <form style="border: radius 10px;border-color:white" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" onsubmit = "return validate()">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div>  
                <center> <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery" style="color:white">FULL NAME</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control" name="fullname" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" /><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">MOBILE NUMBER</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control"name="contact" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number" /><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">License Id</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control"name="license_no" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your FSSAI License" /><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">Email Id</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control" name="email" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">CITY</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control" name="city" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your City Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">PASSWORD</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control" name="password" id="inputDelivery" type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" /><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">ADDRESS</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control" name="address" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Full Adress" /><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <label class="" for="inputDelivery"style="color:white">Restaurent Name</label>
                      <input class="form-control input-box form-foodwagon-control" name="restaurent_name" id="inputDelivery" type="text" placeholder="Enter Restaurent Name" /><br>
                    </div>

                  <div class="col-4">

                    <label class="form-label" for="customFile" style="color:white">LOGO</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" />
                  </div>

                </div> </center> 
                </div>
                <center><a href=""><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">REGISTER NOW</button></a></center><br>            
              </form>
           </div>
        </div>                      
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```